# SQL Wildcard Query

Tags: sql, sybase

Say there is a channel_name 'DISCOVERY' in a Table A
Is there a way I can write a query

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE CHANNEL_NAME LIKE '%discovery%'
```

(this doesn't return anything because it is in caps). I want to write the spell in any order and yet get the output. Is there a way I can do it? using lower name or anything help?

Comment: In the future, you may want to specify which Sybase product you are using in your question.  Sybase makes several database products, and knowing which one you are using will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lower()](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks230.htm):

```
SELECT * FROM A 
WHERE LOWER(CHANNEL_NAME) LIKE '%discovery%'
```

Answer (score 1):

**[LCASE](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1270/html/iqref/Lcase.htm)**

```
select * FROM A WHERE LCASE(CHANNEL_NAME) LIKE '%discovery%'
```